# How do I redirect all requests for .html files to directories with respective names?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First question so grace is much appreciated! I have a site that use to have tens of thousands of .html files that are now index.html files inside directories. For example, `file1.html` has become `/file1/` (`/file1/index.html`). I don't want to spend inodes on individual files to do this, so I was hoping it'd be possible to do in a htaccess file. I suppose it'd have to test existence of the directory which isn't actually possible right?

Comment: file1.html has become /file1/ or /file1/index.html ?

Comment: The latter, sorry. As a URL, it will always end in just the slash for SEO purposes, if that makes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d # Dir exists?
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: For some reason, doesn't work unless I use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` like so:  
`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d`  ...but works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your the directory that contains all directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(.*)\.html$ 
RewriteRule  .*  /%1/   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't seem to test for directory existence.